# pthread and kinda "broadcast stream"

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

What is the best way to have some shared stream with data for all threads?
If i have a threads interacting with each user connection, and then every users input must be available for all threads. We can imagine like a simple chat, where everyone sees everyones messages.

So i though that i can use some kind of "shared stream", which i can use for some kind of `select()` between this stream and users input socket, to write there when i got an input and read from there when there is something new available. I though about having some shared socket, but it wan't work this way, because when first thread will read data from socket, it wan't be available for othrer threads anymore.

So what it the best and idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: Using `select()` is rather useful for IPC not for internal communication. Internally, a shared queue with an associated event would be a better way, although a multiplexer that writes to individual queues for each thread should also be considered. What exactly do you want?

Comment: You mean every thread examines a sort of queue and recieves last data he didn't recive before, and it should keep tracking what did it already get and what didn't?

Comment: Yes, it's a classing "Producer-Consumer Scenario", just search the web.

Answer (score 0):

I think youy might be taking the engineering here a bit too far.. 
what you are looking for is an SMP [like this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/smp.c) or [this](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) of some sort, not a stream. The "stream" concept could be handled by a different process (a manager process, if you will) that will handle that stream of incoming information. In the chat scenario you described, it's not neccery because each thread can add to the SMP whatever is received on its own input stream.